# How do I configure this one-to-two(?) relationship in EF Core with individual navigation properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create and configure a context based on an existing database and add navigation properties where it isn't defined. I'm not sure how to classify this relationship exactly, I'd say it's two one-to-one relationships.

```
Subject            Owner
-------            ----
SubjectId: int     OwnerId: int
OwnerId: int?      Name: string
CoOwnerId: int?    ====
=======            Subject: Subject
Owner: Owner
CoOwner: Owner
```

(not exact names but same idea)

For every subject, there is an owner and potentially a co-owner. I've tried to set it as multiple one-to-one relationships but it fails at runtime:

```
partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Owner>()
        .HasOne(o => o.Subject)
        .WithOne(s => s.Owner)
        .HasForeignKey<Subject>(s => s.OwnerId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Owner>()
        .HasOne(o => o.Subject)
        .WithOne(s => s.CoOwner)
        .HasForeignKey<Subject>(s => s.CoOwnerId);
}
```

> Cannot create a relationship between 'Owner.Subject' and 'Subject.CoOwner' because a relationship already exists between 'Owner.Subject' and 'Subject.Owner'. Navigations can only participate in a single relationship. If you want to override an existing relationship call 'Ignore' on the navigation 'Subject.CoOwner' first in 'OnModelCreating'.

If I leave only the owner configuration, then it works when querying subjects and including both owners (it even figures out how to map co-owner correctly), but fails if I query owners and try to include the subjects. The navigation is `null` if it happens to be a co-owner.

```
ctx.Subjects
    .Include(s => s.Owner)
    .Include(s => s.CoOwner)
    .Where(s => s.CoOwnerId == 2)
    .Single();
// { Owner: {1}, CoOwner: {2} }

ctx.Owners
    .Include(o => o.Subject)
    .Single(o => o.OwnerId == 1);
// { Subject: { Owner: {1}, CoOwner: {2} } }

ctx.Owners
    .Include(o => o.Subject)
    .Single(o => o.OwnerId == 2);
// { Subject: null }

// ironically, queries involving the coborrower navigation works
ctx.Subjects
    .Where(s => s.Owner.Name == "John"); // works
ctx.Subjects
    .Where(s => s.CoOwner.Name == "Joe"); // also works
```

I guess I would have to configure this as a one-to-many relationship, but I'm not sure how to make this work with the available `ModelBuilder` methods. How can I make this work? Is this a case EF Core does not support?

Comment: What if to inherit new type called `CoOwner` from `Owner`, and create two one-to-one relationships with different types on other side? Semantically looks good - `CoOwner` cries 'i am not the main one'. Also you can just duplicate properties if inheritance is not desired.

Comment: @Ryan I've been playing around with inheritance to do this, to minimize the amount of duplication needed. Probably could have worked fine if only I could figure out how to have it ignore the need for a discriminator and essentially have an "alias" type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subject side is fine, but look at it from the Owner side, there is only one Subject reference. A subject wants two bi-directional references with an Owner and Co-Owner, yet the owner object only has one reference back to a subject, it cannot serve both references.

If the subject only needs a reference to the Owner (not co-owner) then you can make the co-owner subject reference uni-directional:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Owner>()
    .HasOne(o => o.Subject)
    .WithOne(s => s.Owner)
    .HasForeignKey<Subject>(s => s.OwnerId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Subject>()
    .HasOne(o => o.CoOwner)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Subject>(s => s.CoOwnerId);
```

If you do want bi-directional references, then your owner needs two Subject References: Think "SubjectIOwn" vs. "SubjectICoOwn"

Edit: Note that with the uni-directional co-owner navigation, you will need to find co-owners through their subjects. This means if an owner is typically either an owner or co-owner of a particular subject, you wouldn't be able to attack it from the owner:

```
var owners = _context.Owners
    .Where(o => o.Subject.Id == subjectId)
    .ToList();
```

This works for the owner relationship, but cannot find the co-owner of the subject. Instead you would use:

```
var ownerDetails = _context.Subject
    .Where(s => s.Id == subjectId)
    .Select(s => new 
    {
        s.Owner,
        s.CoOwner
    }).Single();
```

from there if you want a collection of owners possibly for a set of subjects you would compose a list of owners and co-owners if they are not #null.

To do it from Owner using bi-directional references you need two subject references:

```
var owners = _context.Owners
    .Where(o => o.SubjectIOwn.Id == subjectId || o.SubjectICoOwn.Id == subjectId)
    .ToList();
```

This would return owners that are either the owner or co-owner of a given subject.

Comment: This does not quite work. The added `Subject` config effectively does nothing. It produces the same results as if it was just the `Owner` config alone. All navigations work, except if the `Owner` entity was a `CoOwner` for a Subject. I would just like to be able to have the two-way navigation to work for any `Owner`.

Comment: The two way cannot be an either-or. To have two-way you would need the "SubjectIOwn" and "SubjectICoOwn" in the Owner if you want to get to a subject that a given owner either owns or sub-owns based on which subject reference is populated.

Comment: I updated the answer to outline this scenario.

Comment: Over all, as long as the navigation from Subject -> Owner is working, I'll be able to move forward. If I can't get it working bi-directional and it annoys me enough that it won't work for the CoOwner, I could live without it.